# How to construct an array of objects programmatically

Tags: jquery, arrays, coffeescript

I want to construct an array of objects programmatically. The end result I am expecting is this

```
[{"nickname":"xxx"},{"nickname":"yyy"},{"nickname":"zzz"}]
```

This is my code

```
@tagged_user_array = []
//pingUsers is the array which stored the list or nicknames 'xxx', 'yyy' and 'zzz'
$.each @pingUsers, (index, nick) =>
   @tagged_user_array.push(nick)
```

With my code above, I am unable to get my expected result. What do I need to modify in order to get my expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var pingUsers = ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"];
var tagged_user_array = [];

$.each(pingUsers, function(index, value)  {
    tagged_user_array.push({ "nickname" : value });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qPaDL/)

I'm not sure why you have prefixed your variables with `@` as this is invalid in javascript.

Comment: The `@`s, lack of parentheses, lack of `var`, and `(...) =>` indicate CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using CoffeeScript and loops are expressions in CoffeeScript, you could use a [comprehension](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) instead:

```
pingUsers = ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"]
tagged_user_array = ({nickname: value} for value in pingUsers)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/w4ugV/1/

Comment: super small tweak... remove the semi-colon. :-)